# C++ serializing an object containing an array of other objects

Tags: c++

I have the object listed below.

```
class Customer
{
private:
    std::string customerName;
    std::string customerLastName;
    std::string customerIdentityNumber;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> customerAccounts;

}
```

How would one go about serializing this object? I've tried finding examples but these are all using some complex libraries. Surely there must be an easier way?

Coming from Java this is new to me.

Comment: What did you tried, what is `Account`?

Comment: You're wither going to make sure every type has a `operator >>` and `operator <<` defined and then write it out to a file or use a library like boost::serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend a serialization library such as [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Its a great library, easy to use, extremely fast, and has much more than just this!

It's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a very simple and basic implementation. Lets assume that `Serialize()` function has already been implemented for `Account` class.

The implementation of `Serialize()` function of `Customer` class can be:

```
void Customer::Serialize(Archive& stream)
{
    if(stream.isStoring())  //write to file
    {
        stream << customerName;
        stream << customerLastName;
        stream << customerIdentityNumber;
        stream << customerAccounts.size(); //Serialize the count of objects
        //Iterate through all objects and serialize those
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>>::iterator iterAccounts, endAccounts;
        endAccounts = customerAccounts.end() ;
        for(iterAccounts = customerAccounts.begin() ; iterAccounts!= endAccounts; ++iterAccounts)
        {
            (*iterAccounts)->Serialzie(stream);
        }
    }
    else   //Reading from file
    {
        stream >> customerName;
        stream >> customerLastName;
        stream >> customerIdentityNumber;
        int nNumberOfAccounts = 0;
        stream >> nNumberOfAccounts;
        customerAccounts.empty();  //Empty the list
        for(int i=0; i<nNumberOfAccounts; i++)
        {
            Account* pAccount = new Account();
            pAccount->Serialize(stream);
            //Add to vector
            customerAccounts.push_back(pAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is self-explanatory. But idea is to archive count and then every element. This help while deserializing from file.